# How to Create Terraform code for GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

We can create/see the gcloud command from GKE cluster creation UI , is there a way to convert the command into terraform code for GKE cluster. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create GKE cluster by using terraform. There is a official [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html), by following you need to write the .tf file and apply.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "my-gke-cluster"
  location = "us-central1"

  initial_node_count       = 1

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""

    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }
}
```

[This](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/kubernetes/provision-gke-cluster) is an useful tutorial.